# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource on wsimport Intellij java 9

Tags: web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl, java-9, wsimport

i'm trying to generate class stubs for a wsdl with Intellij-Idea 2017.2.5 (Webservices -> Generate code from wsdl...) using JDK-9

I'm getting this exception and i wonder how to tell intellij to pass "--add-modules java.activation" to complete the operation.

(i guess i should run wsimport from the command line...)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:461)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BindInfo.getJAXBContext(BindInfo.java:335)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.SCDBasedBindingSet.apply(SCDBasedBindingSet.java:235)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:541)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2244)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:137)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:391)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:204)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:135)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89031.

Comment: ^^ Seems like the command line would be the only option left in that case.

Comment: Have you tried setting global environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS=--add-modules java.activation`? IDEA restart will be required.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov already tried

Answer (score 43):

Based on your error message, you need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

From SDK 9, for JAXB to work for web services you need to also have the following dependencies if you do not already have them as they are not part of the SDK.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For gradle builds, add `compile('javax.activation:activation:1.1')` (check the correct version on [maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation)).

Comment: Thanks,I added `/tomcat/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar` file and error went away, JDK10+Tomcat8.5

Comment: Eclipse foundation has taken over JavaEE development. `javax.activation` has moved to `jakarta.activation` per https://wiki.eclipse.org/New_Maven_Coordinates

Answer (score 5):

I guess it can be useful. I have these additional packages in my soap project when switch from Java 8 to 10. Gradle:

```
compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
compile "javax.activation:activation:1.1"
compile "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0"
compile "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0"
compile "com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.0"
compile "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.0"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for other people with the same exception coming here:

This problem can also occur if you use a web server such as tomcat and if you need the activation jar to be present there as well. One possible solution is to put it in the lib folder of tomcat (or to use the common.loader functionality).

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped me out. Just downloaded from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1 and added to my project build path (school project, can't use maven).

Comment: @markus-barthlen Thank you! That was just what I have been looking for for a few days! Now my `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource` is gone :)

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem. After changing the project jdk, it works for me.

Change project jdk to 8.

Comment: I don't know why they've downvoted you. This solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: This solution is being downvoted because while downgrading the JDK works, it's a bad idea to to so. Java 8 isn't really supported any more. This just opens up the door to a number of other issues, not to mention security risks.